# Python Record Linkage Toolkit - Qgrams Error

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror, record-linkage

I have been following the example record linking code from the Python [Record Linkage Toolkit](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/link_two_dataframes.html) package and it runs fine when using the 'jarowinkler' string matching method. However when running with method = "qgram" or "cosine" it throws a numpy error. Any thoughts on what may be causing the error?

> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\recordlinkage\compare.py",
> line 153, in _compute_vectorized
> c = c.where((c < self.threshold) | (pandas.isnull(c)), other=1.0)
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'where'

Code for Reference:

```
import recordlinkage
from recordlinkage.datasets import load_febrl1

##### Functions Correctly

dfA = load_febrl1()

# Indexation step
indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.block(left_on='given_name')
candidate_links = indexer.index(dfA)

compare_cl = recordlinkage.Compare()

compare_cl.string('surname', 'surname', method='jaro', threshold=0.1, label='surname')

features = compare_cl.compute(candidate_links, dfA)
matches = features[features.sum(axis=1) > 0]
print(len(matches))

##### Fails with:
#     AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'where'

dfA = load_febrl1()

# Indexation step
indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.block(left_on='given_name')
candidate_links = indexer.index(dfA)

compare_cl = recordlinkage.Compare()

compare_cl.string('surname', 'surname', method='qgram', threshold=0.1, label='surname')

features = compare_cl.compute(candidate_links, dfA)
matches = features[features.sum(axis=1) > 0]
print(len(matches))
```

Answer (score 0):

for qgram and/or cosine method, remove the threshold value